# Can't push to new repo in Github

Tags: git, bash, github

This is my problem when I push my new repo in GitHub.

```
$ git push switchy master
remote: Permission to switchyofficial/switchy.git denied to jrey211995.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/switchyofficial/switchy.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The `jrey211995` was my first account, then I created another account for my new repo. After that, I added, I commit it, and then when I push it to my new account, that problem is always appearing, how can I solve that?

**Note:** The `jrey211995` is set to auto authenticate when I push a repo in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your new username and email associated with your new GitHub repository in the root directory of your local project:

```
git config --local user.name yourusername
git config --local user.email youremail
```

Then run the following command:

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

By default, Git does not match the path component of a URL, so the urls for two different repos on GiHub still just look like 'https://github.com' to Git.

When `credential.useHttpPath` is set to true, Git considers the entire URL for matching. So you can have access to different repos with different credentials for each one.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I had the same issue not too long ago.